# Intersection of a sphere and cylinder (Viviani´s Curve)

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $-1<a<1$ and $C_a$ be the curve given by the intersection of the sphere of center $\textbf{0}$ and radius 2 and cylindre at a distance $(1-\cos(\pi a))$ from $\textbf{0}$ and of radius $(1+\cos(\pi a))$. Assume that the cylinder intersects x-axis. Find the parametrization of $C_a$.

Since the cylinder is at a distance $(1-\cos(\pi a))$ from $\textbf{0}$ and has radius $(1+\cos(\pi a))$, we have that the axis of the cylindre has coordinates $(x,y)=(2,0)$. The we have both equations:

$x^2+y^2+z^2=4$

$(x-2)^2+y^2=(1+\cos(\pi a))^2$

I´ve been thinking about these two options:

(Option A) Write the parametrization of the sphere: $(2\cos(v)\sin(u), 2\sin(u)\sin(v), 2\cos(u))$. Then substitute coordinates $(x,y)$ on cylindre's equation:

$(2\cos(v)\sin(u)-2)^2+( 2\sin(u)\sin(v))^2=(1+\cos(\pi a))^2 \iff (\cos(v)\sin(u)-1)^2+( \sin(u)\sin(v))^2=(\frac{1+\cos(\pi a)}{2})^2$

We need to do $\sin(u)=\cos(v)$, isn´t it? But how?

(Option B) The parameterization of the cylindre is $((1+\cos(\pi a))\cos(t)+2, (1+\cos(\pi a))sin(t))$ and let´s find $z$. If we substitute this on the equation of the sphere: Let $R=(1+\cos(\pi a))$

$(R\cos(t)+2)^2+(R\sin(t))^2+z^2=4 \iff R^2\cos(t)^2+4R\cos(t)+4+R^2\sin(t)^2+z^2=4 \iff R^2+R\cos(t)+z^2=0 \iff z^2=-R(R-\cos(t))$ But then $R(R-\cos(t))$ must be negative. I found this way harder.

Any hint please?

Comment: How did you get to axis of the cylinder as $(x = 2, y = 0)$? It is not clear to me.

Comment: The question is not very clear. It gives distance from origin to the cylinder but the cylinder could be anywhere at that distance and not necessarily with its axis on $x-$axis.

Comment: Sorry cylinder intersecting $x-$axis was by assumption. I forgot it on the statement

Comment: The orginal statement we have to prove that exits a motion that transform a random postitioning of cylinder and sphere to the curremt situation